# apt update always overrides old config file

Tags: apt, deb

I am building and distributing my code as a deb package (built with cmake, packaged with CpackDeb) to a Ubuntucore-based 16.04 LTS. The package installs a config file among else. I can't get apt/apt-get to keep the old configuration file during an update. It silently overrides the old config in all test cases and regardless of whether it had been edited or not. Things I tried:

```
$ apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install <package>

$ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ; apt-get install -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" <package>
```

And some variations. The result is always the same - a silent override of the old config file. apt version is 1.2.31, I am on an arm64 processor.

Maybe I am not packaging the deb correctly? My config file is simply an installable. I'm not aware of any special requirements for config files, are there any?

Comment: Where is your config file installed? Are you using `debhelper` to build your package?

Comment: I am using Cmake's CPackDeb. Installed to /etc/<foo>/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include a `conffiles` file in your control `control.tar.gz`.  When creating a package with [dpkg-deb](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dpkg/dpkg-deb.1.en.html) this is placed in `DEBIAN/conffiles`.  This file should have exactly one line for every config file contained in your debian package.  Each line specifies the full path of a config file.

See https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dpkg-dev/deb-conffiles.5.en.html

The result of including this will be that these files are registered on the system as config files and will not be automatically overwritten.

---

I've not used CPackDeb myself, but there's a reference for how to add files to `control.tar.gz` here:

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPackDeb.html?highlight=conffiles

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR/prerm;${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/postrm")
```

Comment: ... assuming you're using `dh_installdeb` which I've never bothered to.  But okay I'll edit

Comment: You’re making a few assumptions which are liable to confuse readers. If building from source, you hardly ever manipulate `DEBIAN` directly. If you write a `conffiles` in your control directory, it won’t be taken into account in `debhelper` compatibility level 12 or later. Of course if you don’t use `debhelper` then you need to deal with things yourself but that’s not what I’d expect new packagers to do...

Comment: Aha, so I am indeed not packaging correctly. Any idea how to achieve that behavior with CPack? Will look into CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_CONTROL_EXTRA.

Comment: I can see the ambiguity with `debhelper`'s nomenclature.  I've edited to quantify the use of the `DEBIAN` directory for `dpkg-deb` although I note a `conffiles` file for installation into `DEBIAN` is also correct for `debhelper` where it does not automatically find config files.  The underlying file format doesn't use the name `DEBIAN` and I was unaware of any name collisions with other packaging utilities.

Comment: @Philip thanks, your answer seems OK to me now. The assumptions I was referring to were that (1) that users were building binary packages directly, using `dpkg-deb` (which you’ve made explicit) and (2) that `conffiles` is a universal solution — as mentioned above, in the current compatibility level (12), `debhelper` will ignore any `conffiles` provided in the packaging.